# JavaRx call onComplete when condition is true

Tags: java, rx-java2

I'm collecting messages from an observable which is parsing messages coming in over a serial connection.

I have a piece of code that looks like this,

```
Observable<Message> observer = SerialCommunication.create(portName)
                   .collect(new ArrayList<Byte>(), new ByteParser())
                   .filter(MessageParser::isMessageDone)
                   .map(MessageParser::parse);
```

I have another reference to the `SerialCommuncation` which I use to send messages through, so what I need is to call `onComplete()` on this, once I have received the response messages I expect.

I however can't come up with the correct way of deciding to call the `onComplete()` without doing it either too fast (so I don't actually receive all the responses), too slow or not at all.

In essence the question is, how do I call `onComplete()` at the time where I have received for example 5 responses to the 5 requests I sent.

Comment: Is `5` a magic number? How do you know when you done processing all the data? In RxJava terms, set up the observer chain to complete when all actions are done. You can use the `toList()` operator to collect all the results at the end of processing, and at that point, use `doOnNext()` to signal the other observer chain that it should be completed.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.